# Looping through a double sorted table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mySQL database with names and medical prescriptions. What I what to do is loop through all prescriptions belonging to a specific name and show them in a table, and then create a new table whit the next name and a new set of prescriptions.

I know how to sort the table (ORDER BY elevnavn ASC, start_dato DESC), start_date, being the date the prescription was given, but I do not know how to split each name into different tables.

I am getting the table in wordpress with

```
 $medicinskemaer = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}medicin_skema WHERE aktiv = 1 ORDER BY elevnavn ASC, start_dato DESC", ARRAY_A ) ?: [];
```

I would like to populate a table using a foreach loop. As of now, I am just posting the headers of the table, and for each paired row, I post the name and medical schema.

How do I break up the tables, so that they only show the name once and then loop through all the prescriptions, then move on to the next name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should use `GROUP BY name`, more info [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-handling.html).

Comment: When I use GROUP BY, I am able to display the name of a patient and the first table row. But I do not know how to populate rows from the sub_fields within the groups. I have tried with GROUP_CONCAT, and it allows me to show a all rows of a column from the group, but still I need to populate all the data from the sub rows.